# How to get image URL inside DIV

Tags: puppeteer

I would like to ask on how to get the image URL if the image is inside DIV

```
<div style="background-image: url(https://img.vggcdn.net/img/cat/11554/2/13.jpg);" class="ibk radius-circle bkgdCover bkgd-nr profile-image"></div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Some clues here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3786

Answer (score 0):

no need for this i already got the answer

```
let event_image = document.querySelector('div.ed-event-image-container').childNodes[1].style.backgroundImage;
    event_image = event_image.split(/"/)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem from this way,

```
 await page.goto('Enter your page url');
    await page.waitFor(5000);
    let serachElement =".profile-image";
    /**
     * Check for image exit or not then return image 
     * otherwise return Image not found message
     * 
     */
    let checkForElement = await page.evaluate((sel)=>{
           let elementCheck =Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(sel));
           if(elementCheck.length){
               return elementCheck[0].style.backgroundImage
           }else return 'Image not found';

    },serachElement);
```